# Setting environment variables in Eclipse to use with Android NDK

Tags: eclipse, makefile, android-ndk, cygwin, environment-variables

I use Android NDK with cygwin with Eclipse on Windows.
In my makefile I want to set path of prebuild library using environment variable in eclipse.
So I do the following:

[image]

And in makefile:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(QCAR_SDK_ROOT)build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(QCAR_SDK_ROOT)build/include
```

But I get error:

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:QCAR-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/android-ndk-r7/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
Android NDK: Check that jni//cygdrive/D/Development/Android/qcar-android-1-5-4-beta1/build/lib/armeabi/libQCAR.so exists  or that its path is correct
```

Tried defining variable in makefile directly, got the same result.

So, obviously, that path is not what I wanted. How do I set the proper path?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just specify the paths in the make file? (N.B Just noticed you tried that.)

[Using Cygwin with Android NDK](http://pielot.org/2010/12/09/using-cygwin-with-the-android-ndk-on-windows/)

This site seems to indicate that the make file won't run correctly within Eclipse and you should run in via Windows Explorer. Are you running this within Eclipse? Try this and see if you still get the issues.

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem of the previous NDK builds that Google fixed with NDK-9. "Updated ndk-build to support absolute paths in LOCAL_SRC_FILES."

See the release notes here:http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `LOCAL_PATH` variable. As documentation (`docs/ANDROID-MK.html` in Android NDK package, or [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/development/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.TXT)) states:

> `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`
>
> This is a list of source files that will be built for your module.
>       Only list the files that will be passed to a compiler, since the
>       build system automatically computes dependencies for you.
>
> Note that source files names are all relative to `LOCAL_PATH` and
>       you can use path components

Also, NDK hints you to `Check that jni//cygdrive/D/Development/Android/qcar-android-1-5-4-beta1/build/lib/armeabi/libQCAR.so exists  or that its path is correct`.

Thus, I would try the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := /
```

...or to reset it at all:

```
LOCAL_PATH :=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `eclipse.ini` file and add it there.

e.g. `-DLOCAL_SRC_FILES=/home/user/.../`

Or declare a [path variable](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cpathvars.htm). It is a convenient way of sharing a common location among multiple projects within a workspace.

Hope that help you!

Answer (score 0):

Recent NDK releases on Windows do not need cygwin. Worse, they do not recognize the cygdrive notation. You can simply use

```
QCAR_SDK_ROOT = D:/Development/Android/qcar-android-1-5-4-beta1
```

**correction** absolute paths for LOCAL_SRC_FILES do not work for ndk.r7, and even for r9 the ANDROID-MK.doc does not encourage using absolute paths there.