# Cannot find module with tag 'extensions' in import path

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Although this question is asked many times but none of the solutions worked for me. I have declared NDK_MODULE_PATH as well but still i get this error:

```
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'extensions' in import path
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ? 
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
jni/Android.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

My android.mk files looks like this:

```
 LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static
 LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ezibyte_social_static
 LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
 LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static

 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


 $(call import-module,extensions)
 $(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) 
 $(call import-module,cocos2dx) 
 $(call import-module,ezibyte/ezisocial/android)
```

Please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

I hope this [link](http://www.programering.com/a/MDO3QjMwATA.html) helps you.

**The role of NDK_MODULE_PATH**

NDK_MODULE_PATH is a very important variable, when the android.mk is used in the $(call import-module, XXX) function into external libraries will be used, to indicate where to find this file. 
If NDK_MODULE_PATH is not set or not set correctly. Compile time error Are is you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined.

**Setting and format of NDK_MODULE_PATH**

NDK_MODULE_PATH is an environment variable, variable settings is not android.mk. 
NDK_MODULE_PATH multiple paths for colon segmentation. Not a semicolon! And the whole string with no whitespace. Not in the correct format can be error above the wrong.

**Method of setting NDK_MODULE_PATH**

1. Add the environment variables manually in the environment.
2. Run ndk-build in build_native.sh before using the export command defines the environment variable NDK_MODULE_PATH.
   Such as: export NDK_MODULE_PATH= path 1: path 2: path 3
3. Directly behind the parameter NDK_MODULE_PATH= path 1: path 2 is added to the ndk-build command. The ndk-build parameter will directly transmitted to the make
   Such as: $NDK_ROOT_LOCAL/ndk-build -C $HELLOWORLD_ROOT NDK_MODULE_PATH= path 1: path 2
   (command make aaa=213 // before compiling makefile AAA as environment variables set to 213)
4. You can set the NDK_MODULE_PATH in Android.mk
   Join in before the import statement, 
   $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt)

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand how to add environment variable manually? Do I need to set in the My Computer->Advanced Properties?

Comment: yes. it should be their in the environment variables..plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925485/setting-environment-variables-in-eclipse-to-use-with-android-ndk